# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python

My following code doesn't work and I don't get why

```
from time import time
t=time.clock()
print(t)
```

The error is 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'clock'

I don't understand where is the mistake because on all examples I have seen such code should work.

What's more, if I replace time.clock() by time(), the code works (so the library is "recognized").

Comment: Just use `import time` instead `from time import time`. `time` is a python module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` has an attribute `clock`, you are trying to access `time.time.clock` which does not exist.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.clock()
0.126727
>>> time.time()
1513247982.472323
>>> time.time.clock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: My question is probably obvious but I'm beginner in python. When I do from time import time then all the method will be in time.time, but if I directly do import time, all the method are in time. That is how it works in general ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But I'll try to answer anyway. If you do `from time import time` then you imported `time.time` under the name `time`. Is that clear? It's like typing `from math import exp`, then you imported `math.exp` under the name `exp`.

Comment: Yeah in fact that is ok, I just wanted to understand mor what the keywords mean precisely because for me at this point now it works but I don't really understand what "from" mean for example. But I will see it on internet now bc it is not directly link to the question.

Thanks anyway you answered my questions !

Comment: There is a `time` library that contains, among other things, `time` and `clock`.  With dotted notation they would be `time.time` and `time.clock` respectively.  By doing `from time import time` you are only importing `time.time`.  You can either `from time import clock` and then call `clock` in your code, or you can `import time` and call `time.clock` in your code.